# Jquery Click Event Is Larger Than Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having some issues with the Jquery click event. The event is firing when I click the button but it also will fire when I click to the side of the button which produces an undesirable affect in the application I'm building. I've included a JSFiddle below which demonstrates this issue. If you click to the right of the 'Next' button the event will still fire. Also if you take out the javascript this behavior disappears.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9nyk/2/)

Javascript shown below:

```
$(function() {

$(" #sortable ").sortable({axis: "x", containment: "window"});
$( ".clicked" ).click( function() {

   var sortedIDs = $( "#sortable" ).sortable( "toArray", {attribute: 'custom-cl'} );
   alert(sortedIDs);

   var target = "http://localhost:3000/langs";

   $.ajax({
     type: 'get',
     url: target + '?order='+sortedIDs.join(',') ,
     dataType: 'script'
   }); 
});     
});
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue and contain the click event within the button?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your click handler is set on the div that contains the button. If you want it only for the button element, give it an id and set it on that instead.

```
<div class="clicked"><button id="next" type="button">Next</button></div>

$('#next').click(function(){..});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `div` has `display:block` by default (which has width `100%` of parent), you can just set it to `inline-block`:

```
.clicked {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/n9nyk/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well. I didn't realize the defaults that came with using div.

Comment: @mtcrts70 and I thought you surely knew `.clicked` is a div, not a button, also wrapping a div around a button should have some relevant reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
<div class="clicked"><button type="button">Next</button></div>
```

into this

```
<div><button type="button"  class="clicked">Next</button></div>
```

and try

Answer (score 1):

why not change to this:

```
$( ".clicked button" ).click( function() {
```